# Java listFiles in directory in jar

Tags: java, io

Is there any way to use `listFiles()` on a directory that's been packaged into a jar?

Let's say I have a directory in my resource directory with some text files: `texts/text1.txt` and `texts/text2.txt`.

And within this Java program I have a class that needs to use `listFiles()` to get a list of those files. I'll get something like `jar:file:/home/soupkitchen.jar/!text`. I'd expect that to be a directory. Is there any way to be able to treat it as a `java.io.File` directory containing files? Right now it seems to only be listed as neither a file nor directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  java.io.File can only be used to list real directories.

However, you can treat it as a java.nio.file.Path.

Overall, you have three options:

1. Open the .jar as a [Zip File System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) and use [Files.newDirectoryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-) or [Files.list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-).
2. Iterate through all entries in the .jar file, looking for names that match.
3. Put a text file in your .jar that contains the names of all the entries in the directory, so you don't have to try to list them.

Comment: One liner for solution 2: `new JarFile(new File(ThisClassName.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI())).entries()`

Comment: @Torsten Not a good idea, since [getCodeSource() can return null](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource%28%29), and there is no guarantee that a .jar file exists at a `file:` URL.